# How to play video with the .NET Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, video

What is the best way to play video using C# and [.NET Compact Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compact_Framework) 3.5?

I found this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa454909.aspx#working_with_multimedia_topic6

But I can't find the required libraries on my disk. Right now I'm trying to download some Windows Media Player SDKs and hope the libraries will be in there.
And I want to ask you if this is right way to play video on the Pocket PC device?

Answer (score 1):

A bit a late answer, but perhaps [DirectShow.NETCF](http://alexmogurenko.com/blog/directshownetcf/) is something for you. Haven't tested it, but it's worth the try.